# Inner product of vectors with largest projections from two coordinate systems

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose we have a vector $e \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and two coordinate systems with orthonormal bases $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_r\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k\}$, $k,r\leq m$. Suppose

$$e=\sum_{i=1}^r a_iv_i = \sum_{j=1}^k b_jw_j $$

and that $a_i,b_j>0$, $a_1=\max a_i$, $b_1=\max b_j$ and $\langle v_i,w_j \rangle\geq 0$, $\forall i \in \{1,\ldots, r\}$,$\forall j \in \{1,\ldots, k\}$.

Find a lower bound for $\langle v_1,w_1 \rangle$.

Please share some ideas for the problem!

Many thanks!

Comment: Please edit the original question with that transcribed into mathjax from the image.

Comment: Please learn MathJax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I suppose you have $\langle v_1,w_1 \rangle \geq 0$, but you want something tighter. I'd try to look at $\|\sum_i a_i v_i - \sum_j b_j w_j\|^2=0$ and work out from there.

Comment: Thank you Raskolnikov. Yes, I want a tighter bound. I tried the equation but seemed hard to get a result. Is it possible to solve it by some geometry insights?